# Tabview does not change tab on touch

Tags: android, tabs, touch

I have looked around google and stack overflow to find a solution to this but I can't seem to understand why I can't get it to work, I follow everything I see.
my problem here is that whenever I touch on a tab it does not change to the tab I have chosen. looking at the moment I am following directions from [This Stackoverflow post][1] Please note that the tabs work when swiping perfectly

Here is the XML for the tabview.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have added this as well in my main activity. (container is for my recycler view)

```
  TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);  
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

also in my main activity, I have this Method to create my tabs. (the tabnames and fragment names where edited in this post)

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new 1_Fragment(),"tab1");
    adapter.addFragment(new 2_Fragment(),"tab2");
    adapter.addFragment(new 3_Fragment(),"tab3");
    adapter.addFragment(new 4_Fragment(),"tab4");
    adapter.addFragment(new 5_Fragment(),"tab5");
    adapter.addFragment(new 6_Fragment(),"tab6");
    adapter.addFragment(new 7_Fragment(),"tab7");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

also In the main activity, I have this but it does not seem to work on click. though with a Log.d I checked and it works when swiping.

```
   tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
              viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
              Log.d("Tab", String.valueOf(tab.getPosition()));
          }

          @Override
          public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

          }
      });
```

Comment: The `ViewPager` is covering the `TabLayout`, because `CoordinatorLayout` basically acts like a `FrameLayout` for children without `Behavior`s. You can actually put the `TabLayout` inside the `ViewPager`, and it will handle the positioning. `TabLayout` will then take care of setting itself up, so you can omit the `setupWithViewPager()` call.

Comment: Actually, if those are the only things you're going to have in the `CoordinatorLayout`, then you're not really using `CoordinatorLayout` for what it was designed. You could just change it to a vertical `LinearLayout`, if that's the case.

Comment: viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

Comment: tyr to add above line of code

Comment: Tried that code nothing changed. 
@MikeM I also tried your solution. it works but the tab view pushes my recyclable view way down

Comment: Tried which, do you mean?

Comment: sorry I pressed Enter , did not know it will post it.

Comment: Well, changing to a vertical `LinearLayout` will just stack them vertically, edge to edge, so that'd be as close as they can get to each other. If there's a gap, or whatever you mean, with that setup, then there might be a issue with the page layout.

Comment: Yes I stil lget the gab with linear layout. I posted a picture so you can check it.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like something in the page layout, or maybe even with the `RecyclerView` itself. The `TabLayout` should stop right under the tab indicator. You could turn on "Show layout boundaries" in Developer options to check, or even just put a background color on the `TabLayout` temporarily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177176/discussion-between-demeteor-and-mike-m).

Answer (score 0):

Use Relative layout in parent or CoordinatorLayout as below code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/color_light_blue_1"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector_products"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Move `TabLayout` to bottom of `ViewPager`